# jquery plugin not converting JSON string correctly

Tags: jquery, json, comet, nan

I'm getting a JSON string through a comet request.  The string is as follows:

```
"{"tab":2,"changedData":{"from":{"line":20,"ch":0},"to":{"line":20,"ch":0},"text":["a"]},"cmd":"copyChunk","timestamp":1329409543902,"person":{"comradeID":"4ef37369b4812","firstName":"","lastName":"","fullName":"ben team2","nickName":"ben t.","messageCount":0,"email":"ben+team2@squadedit.com","lastPing":1329409537308,"sessionLeader":true,"cursorPosition":{"line":0,"ch":0}}}"
```

I run it through the jquery json plugin:

```
var r = $.evalJSON(jsonstring);
```

But it will not convert the "changeData" object correctly.  The rest of it all works, but changedData.from.line and changedData.to.line both result in NaN.

I've also tried sending changedData.from.line as a string and then using

```
Number(changedData.from.line)
```

to convert it back to a number, but it still returns NaN.  I'm almost positive that 20 is a number, but I've been wrong before.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I apologize, the quotes at the beginning and end aren't actually part of the string. The pitfalls of copy/paste.

Here is the code in context:

```
onMessage : function(frame)
{
    //This function calls the handlers.
    //this is fired every time we recieve a message from orbited
    //this is what calls the handler functions
    //body is a json string containing whatever data was sent via the send() function

    delete r;
    //convert the body to an object
    var r = $.evalJSON(frame.body);
```

where "frame.body" is the string posted above without quotes.

Comment: The code you've put above is not valid js syntax; it has " marks at the beginning/end and internally; JSON is valid syntax, so this can't be exactly what you are receiving. Also, I think you're going to find the problem is in some processing of the data, so we'll most certainly need more code and context.

Comment: Are you sure you're using jQuery? The function evalJSON() is a prototype function. ( http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/evalJSON ) In jQuery, the equivalent would be .parseJSON(). Also, if it were a malformed string, evalJSON() would return with error, so it must be how you're processing the data.

Comment: I'm using the json plugin for jquery from here:  http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/  Also, parseJSON() does the same thing.

Comment: What on earth is `delete r` supposed to do?

Comment: Just making sure that the variable `r` is fresh and not still hung up anywhere else by a global variable.

Comment: That does not make any sense, r is a local variable. Also delete only works for properties of objects: like `delete obj.prop` removes the `prop` property of `obj`, it does not work with variables. Moreover, you're overwriting it right after that line, get rid of that delete!

Comment: Any specific reason you're using a plugin to parse json instead of the standard `JSON.parse()`? And for backward compatibility o JSON.parse you can use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 1):

Error is somewhere else. Using `parseJSON` works perfectly with the string you've given http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/qG6Qv/1/

```
var str = '{"tab":2,"changedData":{"from":{"line":20,"ch":0},"to":{"line":20,"ch":0},"text":["a"]},"cmd":"copyChunk","timestamp":1329409543902,"person":{"comradeID":"4ef37369b4812","firstName":"","lastName":"","fullName":"ben team2","nickName":"ben t.","messageCount":0,"email":"ben+team2@squadedit.com","lastPing":1329409537308,"sessionLeader":true,"cursorPosition":{"line":0,"ch":0}}}';

var json = $.parseJSON(str);
alert(json.changedData.from.line); //outputs 20
```

It may be that your problem is that you're assigning the return of parseJSON to a variable `r` and then you're trying to do `Number(changedData.from.line)`. There is no variable called `changedData`

Answer (score 0):

The leading and trailing quote marks `"` are invalid.